# Which of these acts are considered adultry or fornication

Tags: allah, sin, punishment, forgiveness, masturbation

Salam i want to know that if masturbation is indeed a major sin but is it adultry or is it fornication and can someone repent or ask forgiveness from it? Are there anyways for it to be erased?

Answer (score 1):

Wa'alaikumussalam Warahmatullahi

Brother, i would assume that you use google translate to translate the word "zina" into English. So there might be some misunderstanding. If you look up the definition of [Adultery](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adultery), there is no way masturbation is classified as adultery. And [Fornification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fornication#:%7E:text=Fornication%20is%20generally%20consensual%20sexual,person%2C%20it%20is%20called%20adultery.), is an act that require a partner, so Masturbation is not fornification.

Staying to the question, how do you repent? By not doing it. And ask forgiveness to Allah. if you want, you can do Salat Al Tawbah.

And indeed you can repent and ask forgiveness to Allah SWT for every sin.

"Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful." (Translation by Sahih Int.)

Az-Zumar verse 53

And Allah knows best.

Comment: Thank you so will i be forgiven?

Comment: Dear brother or sister please reply can i still be forgiven then?

Comment: Yes bro. I assume you get this waswas because of dhaif hadith, or hadith that have no source going around. Such as: Your hand will get pregnant at the day of resurrection if you masturbate (this hadith has no source (cmiiw) so you don't have to believe this). Or Allah has cursed someone who marries his hands (masturbate) (This hadith also have no source). Or there's a hadith that said There's 7 kind of people which Allah will put them into hell as the first people except they repent, and one of them is someone who marries his hand (masturbate). This hadith is dha'if. And Allah knows best.